# Hibernate join on key substring

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am having problem with a hibernate join. I have two tables, dbo.issues and dbo.comments, where each issue can have multiple comments associated to it. In the dbo.issues table, IDs are represented as ISSUE-123456 while in the comments table they are represented as 123456 without the ISSUE- prefix. The simplified code is below.

Issue.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dbo.issues")
//And some named queries
public class Issue
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CallID")
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "issue")
    private List<IssueComment> comments;

    //Getters and setters here
}
```

IssueComment.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dbo.comments")

public class IssueComment implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "issueid")
    private String issueId;

    @Column(name = "comment")
    private String comment;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="SUBSTR(CallID, 7, LEN(CallID))"))
    private Issue issue;

    //Getters and setters here

}
```

When I try to run a query, I get the error:

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'issue_CallID'.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? I only have read-only access to the tables so I can't manipulate them to make my life easier!

Comment: which is the query that you are trying to run? i'm guessing you have a `issue_CallID` somwhere, you can try replacing that with `issue.CallID?` or `dbo.issues.CallID?`.

Comment: I'm using a named query in the Issue entity: `SELECT i FROM SupportIssue i` but I've just enabled debugging and the generated hibernate query is `select comments0_.issue_CallID as issue_Ca4_18_0_, comments0_.issueid as issueid1_31_0_, comments0_.issueid as issueid1_31_1_, comments0_.comment as comment_31_1_, comments0_.issue_CallID as issue_Ca4_31_1_ from dbo.comments comments0_ where comments0_.issue_CallID=?`. So I see now where the `issue_CallID` is coming from but since it is generated by hibernate I'm still not sure how to go about fixing it.